# How to create downloadable csv file from a javascript object consisting of array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object like this:-

```
{
    "SUCCESS": [
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "grapes"
    ],
    "FAILED": ["kiwi"],
    "NOPE": ["peach"]
}
```

I want to have a CSV as follows:-

```
apple  SUCCESS
orange SUCCESS
grapes SUCCESS
kiwi   FAILED
peach  NOPE
```

I figured out this piece of code but unable to iterate over this:-

```
const downLoadCsv = (key, items) => {
    let csvContent = '';
    if (!items.length) {
      return;
    }
    items.forEach((item) => {
      csvContent += `${item},`;
      csvContent += '\n';
    });

    const anchorEle = document.createElement('a');
    anchorEle.href = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURI(csvContent)}`;
    anchorEle.target = '_blank';
    anchorEle.download = `${key}.csv`;
    anchorEle.click();
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the point here is that, as you wrote, `items` is not an array, but an object instead.

What you should do is to iterate both `items` keys and the list of items for each key, so:

```
const downLoadCsv = (key, items) => {
  let csvContent = '';

  Object.keys(items).forEach(status => {
    items[status].forEach(fruit => {
      csvContent += `${fruit},${status}\n`;
    })
  });

  if (csvContent !== '') {
    const anchorEle = document.createElement('a');
    anchorEle.href = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURI(csvContent)}`;
    anchorEle.target = '_blank';
    anchorEle.download = `${key}.csv`;
    anchorEle.click();
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you run this piece of code somewhere?

Comment: No, I mean, not this code in particular, but I used the same technique to iterate over object keys and this implementation make sense to me, according to your scenario, since you need to iterate over object keys and over the list included in each key. Did you had some error?

Comment: By the way I tried now and the function works with `key` as a string, like "test", and `items` as the object you shared in your question. I get a file to download and the data were in the file as expected. If you need to improve it a little bit, eventually, you can check if `Object.keys(items).length` exists before to iterate the keys.